# Problem with hyperref and umlauts in the path of a link

Tags: hyperref, links

I use hyperref to put links to external files into a TeX-document. That works fine until thera are german umlauts in the name of the external file. Is there any workaround?

P.S. It is a problem of the preview function in the editor texstudio. When I open the pdf-file in acrobat raeder, the link works even with umlauts in the path.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. “Working example” means also “not working”: just an example of the code you're confronted with.

Comment: File a bug report with textstudio. As a workaround rename the linked files (if possible).